# How to use std::initializer_list constructor with different types to handle nested braced initializer lists

Tags: json, c++17, variadic-templates, initializer-list

I am looking at the [nlohmann json library](https://github.com/nlohmann/json#examples) and I see that the author made it possible to construct json objects like so:

```
json j2 = {
  {"pi", 3.141},
  {"happy", true},
  {"name", "Niels"},
  {"nothing", nullptr},
  {"answer", {
    {"everything", 42}
  }},
  {"list", {1, 0, 2}},
  {"object", {
    {"currency", "USD"},
    {"value", 42.99}
  }}
};
```

and below the example he states the following:

> Note that in all these cases, you never need to "tell" the compiler
> which JSON value type you want to use. If you want to be explicit or
> express some edge cases, the functions json::array() and
> json::object() will help:

I was intrigued by this and tried implementing my own simplified version of this behavior, but I was unsuccessful. I am having trouble getting the initializer list to accept different types at the same time. I also tried analyzing the actual source code of the nlohmann library, and I see that his json object also has one constructor that accepts an `std::initializer_list` that holds some (as far as I understand) fixed type, but I do not understand how that allows `std::initializer_list` to understand the nested braced initializer lists like in the example.

The condition to determine if the initializer list is representing a `JSONArray` or `JSONMap` should be as follows:

If every nested element in the list is itself an array of length 2 where the first element is of type can be used to construct a `JSONString` (I am thinking about using something like `std::is_constructible_v<JSONString, T>`), and the second element is something that can be used to construct a `JSONObject`, then we may deduce that the whole initializer list represents a `JSONMap`, otherwise we treat it as a `JSONAarray`

In the end I want to end up with code that looks something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <variant>

class JSONObject;

using JSONString = std::string;
using JSONNumber = double;
using JSONBool = bool;
using JSONNull = nullptr_t;
using JSONArray = std::vector<JSONObject>;
using JSONMap = std::map<std::string, JSONObject>;

class JSONObject {
    public:
        JSONObject() : var{JSONMap{}} {}

        template <typename T>
        JSONObject(std::initializer_list<T> list) {
            // I do not understand how to implement this
        }

    private:
        std::variant<JSONString, JSONNumber, JSONBool, JSONNull, JSONArray, JSONMap> var;
};

int main() {
    JSONObject jsonObj = {
        {"pi", 3.141},
        {"happy", true},
        {"name", "Niels"},
        {"nothing", nullptr},
        {"answer", {
            {"everything", 42}
        }},
        {"list", {1, 0, 2}},
        {"object", {
            {"currency", "USD"},
            {"value", 42.99}
        }}
    };

    return 0;
}
```

While doing some research, I also came accross an idea to make a variadic template constructor for `JSONObject` like so:

```
template <typename... Args> 
JSONObject(Args&&... args) {
   // some fold expression to deduce how to construct the variant
}
```

but even with this, I am having trouble dealing with the nesting braced initializer lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `std::initializer_list` is homogeneous with respect to type -- all the elements are of the same type. The trick is creating a single type that can hold different values. This is where `std::variant` come into play.

The tricky part about using `std::variant` is that it is not recursive, i.e. it cannot hold a value of its own type. There are variant implementations that are recursive such as [rva::variant](https://github.com/codeinred/recursive-variant) and [Boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/variant.html).

Also, if you want to understand the details, [here](https://www.foonathan.net/2022/05/recursive-variant-box/) is a good tutorial on how to implement a recursive variant type.

**Update**

The following code is a rough sketch of using the `rva::variant` for a json like type. The prototype allows for a natural initialization syntax much like `nlohmann` json. It uses the same technique to differentiate between an obect and array.

### Sample Code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "variant.hpp"

using std::cin, std::cout, std::endl;

using JsonBase = rva::variant<
    std::nullptr_t,
    std::string,
    double,
    bool,
    std::map<std::string, rva::self_t>,
    std::vector<rva::self_t>
    >;

class JsonValue : public JsonBase {
public:
    using JsonBase::JsonBase;
    using InitializerList = std::initializer_list<JsonValue>;

    JsonValue(InitializerList init) {
        bool is_object = std::all_of(init.begin(), init.end(), [](const auto& value) {
            if (std::holds_alternative<std::vector<JsonBase>>(value)) {
                const auto& arr = std::get<std::vector<JsonBase>>(value);
                return arr.size() == 2 and std::holds_alternative<std::string>(arr[0]);
            }
            return false;
        });
        if (is_object) {
            std::map<std::string, JsonBase> m;
            for (const auto& value : init) {
                const auto& arr = std::get<std::vector<JsonBase>>(value);
                const auto& key = std::get<std::string>(arr[0]);
                m.emplace(key, arr[1]);
            }
            *this = m;
        } else {
            std::vector<JsonBase> vec;
            for (auto&& value : init)
                vec.emplace_back(value);
            *this = vec;
        }
    }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const JsonBase& value) {
    if (std::holds_alternative<std::nullptr_t>(value))
        os << "{ }";
    else if (std::holds_alternative<std::string>(value))
        os << "\"" << std::get<std::string>(value) << "\"";
    else if (std::holds_alternative<double>(value))
        os << std::get<double>(value);
    else if (std::holds_alternative<bool>(value))
        os << std::boolalpha << std::get<bool>(value);
    else if (std::holds_alternative<std::map<std::string, JsonBase>>(value)) {
        os << "{ ";
        for (const auto& [key, value] : std::get<std::map<std::string, JsonBase>>(value))
            os << "{ " << key << " : " << value << " } ";
        os << "]";
    }
    else if (std::holds_alternative<std::vector<JsonBase>>(value)) {
        os << "[ ";
        for (const auto& elem : std::get<std::vector<JsonBase>>(value))
            os << elem << " ";
        os << "]";
    }
    return os;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    JsonValue str = "abc";
    cout << str << endl;

    JsonValue dbl = 1.0;
    cout << dbl << endl;

    JsonValue bol = true;
    cout << bol << endl;

    JsonValue vec = {
        "abc", "def", 1.0, true
    };
    cout << vec << endl;

    JsonValue m = {
        { "key0", 2.0 },
        { "key1", true }
    };
    cout << m << endl;
}
```

### Output

```
"abc"
1
true
[ "abc" "def" 1 true ]
{ { key0 : 2 } { key1 : true } ]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However I still do not understand how using this new variant would solve my problem. Could you explain how the ```initializer_list``` constructor should be implemented in this case?

Comment: Thank you very much for the update. However, the example you showed does not exactly answer my question. Look at this working example I made of your code ([link](https://godbolt.org/z/j4sz8sxaq)). When I try to initialize with nested braced initializer lists, the compilation still fails

Comment: @TheMemeMachine It fails because there is no `int` in the variant types. Changing `2` to `2.0` in your link will make the code compile and work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The key to supporting the initialization syntax like nlohmann's JSON library lies in overloading the constructor to accept different types of initializer lists.

For the outermost initializer list, we can overload on `std::initializer_list<T>`:

```cpp
class JSON {
public:
  JSON(std::initializer_list<std::string> init); // array
  JSON(std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::string, JSON>> init); // object
};
```

This allows us to differentiate between a list of values (array) and a list of key-value pairs (object).

For nested objects, we can recursively call the JSON constructor:

```cpp
JSON(std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::string, JSON>> init) {
  // construct object
}
```

The key is that the nested JSON objects will themselves be constructed from the initializer list, eventually terminating when a base value like string or number is reached.

The variadic template approach can also work, but requires explicitly specifying the types to guide overload resolution:

```cpp
template<typename... Args>
JSON(Args... args) {
  construct(args...); 
}

void construct(std::pair<std::string, JSON>& kv) {
  // handle kv pair  
}

void construct(std::string& s) {
  // handle string
}

// etc
```

Overloading on initializer_list along with recursive construction allows the nested syntax to work nicely.

Comment: could you maybe provide a working example? I am confused with how you wrote the constructor in the first snippet. For arrays you specify strings but arrays can hold any other JSON type, so it should be something like ```std::initializer_list<JSON>```.